# Supported Devices 0 on play console

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Play Console shows "Supported Devices 0".

Questions

1. Should I wait for the publishing to be complete ?
2. Should I expect that Supported Devices number will go up > 0 immediately after upload ?

I need the camera functionality, without camera I am ok if it does not show up on play store of that device.

Relevant portions of my Manifest file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="<mypackagename>">


    <!-- Without this Google Play Store will not support any device -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <!-- For Options menu call support -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- For the background service to run forever -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <!-- For Current Location on Driver App -->
    <permission
        android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- For QR Code -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <!-- Google Cloud Messaging -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- This must be set to true, since Google Maps V2.0 needs this -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="<mypackagename>.InitializingApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${mapsKey}"/>

        <activity
            android:name="<mypackagename>.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="<AppliationName>"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Translucent"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="<mypackagename>.DeviceProvision"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_device_provision"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name="<mypackagename>.PassengerHome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_passenger_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit :

Using `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>` gives me 0 supported devices.

Using `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" required=false/>` gave me full 8900 devices.

What nonsense ? I should be able to only select devices that have a camera. What kinda silly setting is this ?

Also I did not have to wait for publishing to complete, just uploading took the number of supported devices up to 8900.

Answer (score 5):

You get 0 supported devices because you require a non-existing feature. There is no such feature called `android.hardware.camera2`.

[android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) is the package that provides the Camera interface. So, thats the package not the features' label.

If your app requires camera, then choose from these features:

- `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>` - if back camera required
- `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>` - if front ...
- `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>` - any cam will do

Src: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

> Also I did not have to wait for publishing to complete, just uploading
>   took the number of supported devices up to 8900.

Yes, once uploaded play store can access your apk file. So it can run

```
aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>
```

and get your requested device feature list. You can try it yourself. Run it from commandline.