# Whats causing Google Play Console to set my device compatibility to 0?

Tags: android, build, permissions, google-play

Im getting the "Your device isn't compatible with this version." error in Google Play on all devices. Console says the build supports 0 harware devices >:|

Which permissions are causing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.retrographic.sprocket">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>

    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

Manifest File

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.retrographic.sprocket"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 42
        versionName "1.4.1"
    }
```

Happy 2017 !

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one of my contractors put in an obsolete "camera2" permission which was causing Play Console to flip out like this. Deleting the permission solved this.

[Supported Devices 0 on play console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814500/supported-devices-0-on-play-console)